# How to view permissions of file in Google Drive REST API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm just learning how to use Google Drive REST API. I'm currently figuring out the GET method to retrieve file resources and have run into a problem. My end goal to be able to see the permissions resource of a file in my GDrive. However, when I send a GET HTTP request for a specific file ID, I only receive four resources: mimeType, kind, id, and name. I made a dummy Google Doc to illustrate the problem and am processing my requests through Google's "Try this API" tool: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%2213hsjqHI_yw7oO_FWDJr9BV0b6mJXD5Zlirr5I2LuLJI%22%7D

If I input my dummy fileID in the above link and press "EXECUTE," I get the following:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "13hsjqHI_yw7oO_FWDJr9BV0b6mJXD5Zlirr5I2LuLJI",
 "name": "Please help",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
}
```

How do I get access to all of the other resources listed on https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve the values of other metadata using `fields`. When you use this, please click "Show standard parameters" at "Try this API" page. By this, you can see the text box for putting `fields`. When you can confirm the text box, please put the values for `fields` to the text box and "EXECUTE" button.

1. For example, when you want to retrieve the filename, file ID and permissions, please put `id,name,permissions`. In this case, when your URL is modified, it becomes as follows.

   - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7b%22fileId%22%3a%2213hsjqHI_yw7oO_FWDJr9BV0b6mJXD5Zlirr5I2LuLJI%22%2c%22fields%22%3a%22id%2cname%2cpermissions%22%7d
2. If you want to retrieve all values, please use `*` to the fields. In this case, when your URL is modified, it becomes as follows.

   - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7b%22fileId%22%3a%2213hsjqHI_yw7oO_FWDJr9BV0b6mJXD5Zlirr5I2LuLJI%22%2c%22fields%22%3a%22%2a%22%7d

#### Reference:

- [Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)

Comment: @rupumped Thank you for your response.